# how can I prevent everyone from logging into argo cd, except for two groups from keycloak?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, argocd

created argo cd and keycloak in kubernetes cluster . The problem is that I want to log in via SSO, forbidding all users who are not in the group to log into argokd. In keycloak, I created a client id and two groups (devops and others), wrote the following configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-rbac-cm
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-rbac-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
data:
  policy.csv: |-
    g, devops, role: admin
    g, others, role: readonly
  policy.default: 'role:'
```

Comment: I think `policy.default: role:none` or `policy.default: role:''` should work

Comment: @Adiii I'll try and write here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find solution:

delete string

> policy.default: 'role:'

my config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-rbac-cm
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-rbac-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
data:
  policy.csv: |-
    g, devops, role: admin
    g, others, role: readonly
```

now if users who are not specified in policy.csv come in, they do not see service in the application section, the section is displayed, but there are no services there